# Why non optional Any can hold nil?

Tags: swift, option-type

In Swift I can declare a constant of type `Any` and put a `String` into it.

```
let any: Any = "hello world"
```

Good. On the other hand I **cannot** put a `nil` value into `any` because it's not optional.

```
let any: Any = nil

error: nil cannot initialize specified type 'Any' (aka 'protocol<>')
let any: Any = nil
              ^
```

Perfect. But why does the compiler allow me do write the following code?

```
let couldBeNil: String? = nil
let any: Any = couldBeNil
print(any) // nil
```

Doesn't `Any` follow the Swift rule that only an Optional var/let can be populated with `nil`?

> Tested with Xcode Playground 7.2 + Swift 2.1.1

Comment: your not holding nil, your holding an enumeration with a value of .none.

Comment: I recommend to avoid `Any` as much as possible.

Comment: @Sulthan question: is 'T' a 1:1 replacement of 'Any'?

Comment: @DanBeaulieu There is no replacement for `Any` but `Any` basically means "I don't want to use concrete types" and in a strongly typed language that's pretty strange.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

**TL;DR;** Optionals in swift are translated by the compiler to `Optional` enum instances, and since `Any` can map to any value, it can be used to store optionals.

---

How does Swift represent optionals? It does it by mapping `SomeType?` to a concrete implementation of the `Optional` enum:

```
Int? => Optional<Int>
String? => Optional<String>
```

A simplified declaration of `Optional` looks like this:

```
enum Optional<T> {
    case none    // nil
    case some(T) // non-nil
}
```

Now, a variable of type `Any` is able to hold an enum value (or any other kind of value, or even metatype information), so it should be able to hold for example a `nil` String, aka `String?.none`, aka `Optional<String>.none`.

Let's see what happens, though. As we see by the `Optional` declaration, `nil` corresponds to the `.none` enum case for all types:

```
nil == Optional<String>.none // true
nil == Optional<Int>.none    // true
[Double]?.none == nil        // also true
```

So theoretically, you should be able to assign `nil` to a variable declared as `Any`. Still, the compiler doesn't allow this.

But why doesn't the compiler let you assign `nil` to an `Any` variable? It's because it can't infer to which type to map the `.none` enum case. `Optional` is a generic enum, thus it needs something to fill the `T` generic parameter, and plain `nil` is too broad. Which `.none` value should it use? The one from `Int`, the one from `String`, another one?

This gives an error message supporting the above paragraph:

```
let nilAny: Any = nil // error: nil cannot initialize specified type 'Any' (aka 'protocol<>')
```

The following code works, and is equivalent to assigning a `nil`:

```
let nilAny: Any = Optional<Int>.none
```

, as the above `Any` variable is actually holding a valid value of the `Optional` enum.

Indirect assignments work too, as behind the scenes `nil` is converted to `Optional<Type>.none`.

```
var nilableBool: Bool? // nilableBool has the Optional<Bool>.none value
var nilBoolAsAny: Any = nilableBool // the compiler has all the needed type information from nilableBool
```

Unlike other languages, in Swift `nil` corresponds to a concrete value. But it needs a type to work with, for the compiler to know which `Optional<T>.none` it should allocate. We can think of the keyword as providing sugar syntax.

Comment: interesting. I guess that's why I can do `var x = 5`, yet I can't do `var y = nil`, because I get an error: `'nil' requires a contextual type`

Comment: But why does "let any: Any? = nil" work? What is the value of <T> in this case?

Comment: @Damon in that case the generic argument is the protocol `Any`. Since `Any` is a type, it can be used as an argument for `Optional`

Answer (score 10):

From the Swift Docs: "`Any`: The protocol to which all types implicitly conform."

i.e. `typealias Any = protocol<>`

So when you declare `String?`, you could think of that as `Optional<String>`, where `Optional<T>` can be implemented as:

```
enum Optional<T> {
  case Some(T), None
}
```

And enums are Types, so they conform to the `Any` protocol. As stated in the comments, `nil` is not a type (and thus does not conform to `Any`, it is the absence of a value (and in this case no value has no type).

Optionals are baked into the language, and are not regular enums, but it still stands that they conform to `Any` while a typeless `nil` does not.

Answer (score 2):

For anybody looking for a way to check if `Any` contains `nil`:

If calling `po value` will tell you that an `Any` variable contains the value `nil` the following line still doesn't work:

```
if value == nil { ... } // Returns false and generates a warning
```

You have to convert it to a nillable value first before checking, for example when `Any` probably contains a `Date`:

```
if Optional<Date>.none == value as? Date { ... } // Returns true and no warning
```

The following line (thanks to @Shubham) doesn't work however:

```
if Optional<Any>.none == value as? Any { ... } // Does not compile
```

Comment: Swift doesn't allow comparing Optional<Any> to Any, so the last line doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks @Shubham I just tried it in a playground and you're right

Comment: This can be used instead `if case Optional<Any>.none = value`