# check if any property in an object is nil - Swift 3

Tags: swift, class, option-type

Im using Swift 3

Wondering whether any method is available to check if all the properties in an object has value / nil

Eg:

```
class Vehicle {
var name : String?
var model: String?
var VIN: String?
}

let objCar = Vehicle()
objCar.name = "Volvo"

if objCar.{anyProperty} ! = nil {
//Go to other screen
}
```

Im in search of the {anyProperty} method where it returns true only if I have values for all properties of objCar. In our case, objCar has no model and VIN and so {anyProperty} is false and will come out of if loop

Pls advice

Comment: Does it even make sense to have them be optional in the first place? A `Car` ***needs*** to have a `name`, `model,` and `VIN`. Also `model` and `VIN` can't change, so it doesn't make sense to have them be `var` variables

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for pointing out -  but that was just an example I was referring to understand what my requirement was. Sorry couldn't find better example at that moment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would strongly recommend against this. State validation is something which should happen from inside a class. From inside the class, you should know better how to check validity.

```
class Vehicle {
    var name: String?
    var model: String?
    var VIN: String?

    func isReadyToAdvance() -> Bool {
        return name != nil && model != nil && VIN != nil
    }
}

let objCar = Vehicle()
objCar.name = "Volvo"

if objCar.isReadyToAdvance() {
    // Go to other screen
}
```

If there are subclasses with different rules for `isReadyToAdvance()` they can override that method.

---

If `isReadyToAdvance()` doesn't make sense for the base class, then add it as an extension.

```
extension Vehicle {
    func isReadyToAdvance() -> Bool {
        return name != nil && model != nil && VIN != nil
    }
}
```

---

@iPeter asked for something a bit more compact when there are lots of properties.

```
extension Vehicle {
    func isReadyToAdvance() -> Bool {
        // Add all the optional properties to optionals
        let optionals: [Any?] = [name, model, VIN]
        if (optionals.contains{ $0 == nil }) { return false }

        // Any other checks

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any more shorter ways? :P I have more than thirty properties. :P

Comment: @iPeter I don't have much for you, but I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. @Jefferey

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if this should be used for production apps, as I'm not very familiar with reflection in Swift (using `Mirror`) and if it has any negative aspects (performance, etc).

Here goes:

```
class Vehicle {
    var name : String?
    var model: String?
    var VIN: String?
}

let objCar = Vehicle()
objCar.name = "Volvo"
objCar.model = "242DL"
objCar.VIN = "123456"

let hasMissingValues = Mirror(reflecting: objCar).children.contains(where: {
    if case Optional<Any>.some(_) = $0.value {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
})

print(hasMissingValues)
```

`hasMissingValues` will be false in the above example (all properties of `Vehicle` are set). Comment the line where `model` is set, for example, and the value of `hasMissingValues` will now be true.

---

Note: There may be a better way to compare `$0.value` (of type `Any`) to nil. Also, this works for properties of any type (not just `String`) of the class.

Comment: It works with `$0.value as Any? != nil` or `let _ = $0.value as Any?` instead of `case Optional<Any>.some(_) = $0.value`.

Comment: @JefferyThomas, those comparisons aren't working for me. `$0.value` is of type `Any`. For the child where value is not set (i.e. is `nil`), printing `$0.value` prints out `nil`, and printing `$0.value as Any?` prints `Optional(nil)`. However, neither of these when compared with `nil` (using ==) gives `true`. It must be because Swift doesn't naturally allow a variable of type `Any` to be set to nil, even though an `Any` can hold any type, including an `Optional`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644128/why-non-optional-any-can-hold-nil).

Comment: Sorry my bad, I'll leave the original comment even though it's wrong. What do you think of `Mirror(reflecting: $0.value).descendant("some") != nil`? I think it has a clearer meaning than the case comparison.

Comment: Good One. Mirror works for all types except closures I beleive. In my case I have few closures to check the nil values

Answer (score 6):

If you have a lot of fields, you can use this approach:

```
struct S {
    let x: String?
    let y: Int
    let z: Bool

    func hasNilField() -> Bool {
        return ([x, y, z] as [Any?]).contains(where: { $0 == nil})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The better solution is to make struct Equatable and compare with empty etalon

```swift
struct Vehicle: Equatable {
    var name : String?
    var model: String?
    var VIN: String?
}

var objCar = Vehicle()
objCar.name = "Volvo"

if objCar != Vehicle() {
    //Go to other screen
}
```

For cases if you do not want to compare all parameters by yourself or try to not use features that degrade performance (as Mirror)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this problem is

```
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: yourStruct)
let hasNilValues = mirror.children.contains(where: { "\($0.value)" == "nil" })
```