# check if any property in a struct is nil - Swift 4

Tags: swift, class, struct, swift4, option-type

How to check that all properties of a `struct` are not nil, without knowing the number and types of the properties of this `struct`?

So, you may want to check this `struct`:

```
struct Fruit {
 var name: String?
 var fruitType: String?
 var quantity: Int?
}
```

and later another `struct` such as this one:

```
struct Farm {
 var name: String?
 var isOpen: Bool?
 var farmerName: String?
 var location: Location?
 var isCertified: Bool?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol StructExt {
    func allPropertiesAreNotNull() throws -> Bool
}

extension StructExt {
    func allPropertiesAreNotNull() throws -> Bool {

        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)

        return !mirror.children.contains(where: { $0.value as Any? == nil})
    }
}
```

Now testing for both structs should be done the following:

```
var fruit = Fruit() // Assuming with have an initializer for the struct
var farm = Farm() // Assuming with have an initializer for the struct
fruit.allPropertiesAreNotNull() // will return true or false depending on weither or not there is a nil property in that struct
farm.allPropertiesAreNotNull() // will return true or false depending on weither or not there is a nil property in that struct
```

Comment: Returns `true` for `struct Fruit { var name: Int? = nil }` even though all properties *are* nil.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44687935/1187415 for a working solution.

Comment: Use `mirror.children.contains(where: { "\($0.value)" == "nil" })` worked for me