# How does a non optional value obtain a nil value?

Tags: swift

The [Apple documentation TN2151](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) says this for a possible cause of a `EXC_BREAKPOINT` / `SIGTRAP`:

> a non-optional type with a nil value

But code such as this won't compile:

```
var x = "hello"
x = nil
```

So under what circumstances can a non-optional obtain a `nil` value?

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644128/why-non-optional-any-can-hold-nil/34644243 . It gives a nice explanation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Consider something like this in Objective-C bridged to Swift:

```
- (NSObject * _Nonnull)someObject {
    return nil;
}
```

The function is annotated as `_Nonnull`, but will return nil.  This bridged as a non-optional object to Swift and will crash.

Comment: This is the commonest cause. There have been a bunch of iOS (and macOS) APIs incorrectly labelled `_Nonnull`.

Comment: See for example the section titled “Nullability” in [AppKit Release Notes for macOS 10.13](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/index.html): “We fixed a number of places where arguments and return values had incorrect nullability.”

Answer (score 7):

Contrived, but possible:

```
class C {}

let x: C? = nil
let y: C = unsafeBitCast(x, to: C.self)

print(y) // boom
```

Comment: Or just `unsafeBitCast(0, to: C.self)`

Comment: Falling back on [Objective-]C casts to shoot yourself in the foot, always elegant :)

Comment: Just a remark: The unsafeBitCast succeeds because for a reference type, instances of `C` and `C?` are pointers and thus of the same size. With `struct C {}` the  unsafeBitCast would already crash (can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes).

Comment: @MartinR Yeah. That's something I really like, that `Optional` in the case of most structs is a tuple containing a discriminator and the payload struct, whereas `Optional` in the case of classes packs the `nil` value as a 0 pointer

Answer (score 1):

Happens when interoperating with Objective C. An objc-method could be annotated as `nonnull`, but nothing prevents it from returning `nil` anyways. The compiler catches only the most obvious cases and even then it only produces warnings (e.g. when you blatently `return nil;` in a method that is specified as not returning nil.)