# How can we check if b is in fact nil at line #4?

Tags: swift

Running the below piece of code on Xcode 9 playground, I noticed that nil does not equal nil. How can we check if b is in fact nil at line #4?

```
let s: String? = nil
var a: Optional<Any> = .some(s as Any)
if let b = a {
    if b == nil {
        print("b equals nil")
    } else {
        print("b doesn't equal nil. b is \(b)")
    }
}
```

[image]

UPDATE 1:

**I do understand why the behavior is so. What I am looking for is how to check if b is nil since comparing it with nil doesn't work here.**

UPDATE 2:

To avoid confusion, I changed the var name to `b` at line 3 (if let b = a)

UPDATE 3:

The answer turns out to be like this:

```
let s: String? = nil
var a: Optional<Any> = .some(s as Any)
if let b = a {
    if Mirror(reflecting: b).descendant("Some") as? String == nil {
        print("b equals nil")
    } else {
        print("b doesn't equal nil. b is \(b)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are overlooking the fact that `a` is actually a constant now in line #4. Its no longer the `a` defined in line #2, since you are unwrapping it with the same name if line #3 i.e `if let a = a`

Comment: That doesn’t explain the behaviour, though.

Comment: `a` can't be `nil` on line 4. That's the whole point of `if let`.

Comment: @maddy: That’s not true. `let x: Int? = nil; let xx: Int?? = .some(x); if let a = xx { print(a) }` prints `nil`.

Comment: @zoul Thats not the case here isnt it ?

Comment: The way I see it, `a` _is_ `nil` on line 4 – `Optional<String>.none`, to be precise. What doesn’t work as expected is the comparison to `nil` due to hiding the type behind `Any`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644128/why-non-optional-any-can-hold-nil

Comment: I have updated the question to make it clearer what I am asking.

Comment: @zoul: The `a` on line 4 (now called `b`) has type `Any` and is not an optional. Therefore `if b == nil` always fails.

Comment: Agreed. (It’s still `nil`, though? It’s an optional, but seen as `Any` by the compiler.) Do you have an idea why the compiler even allows comparing `Any` to anything else?

Comment: @zoul: The compiler "auto-wraps" `b` into an optional in the comparison to `if Optional(b) == nil { ... }`

Comment: Ah! I see. It makes sense. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MartinR Awesome!

Comment: @ThanhPham Don't edit your question to include the answer. Instead, post an actual answer below.

Comment: It’s locked man @rmaddy

Answer (score 2):

When you write:

```
let s: String? = nil
```

You basically create a generic enum value: `s: Optional<String> = .none`

```
enum Optional<T> {
    case .some(T)
    case .none
}
```

Then you wrap that value into a new enum as associated value for `.some` :

```
var a: Optional<Any> = .some(s as Any)
```

which is the same as typing:

```
var a: Optional<Any> = .some(Optional<String>.none as Any)
```

so a by itself is not nil. It contains `.some` value wrapped.
When you unwrap it, you still get nested wrapped Optional. This is why you pass further than line #4. But inherent value of Optional is still `nil`. This is why you see it printed.

Comment: this should be the correct answer. as it explains that 'a' by itself is not nil but a generic Optional object with a 'Wrapped' value in it, thats why the if let statement succeeds.

Comment: what is the result if you assign as `let a:Any? = s as Any`

Comment: IMHO the _real_ question here is why the comparison with `nil` in `a == nil` fails, and that’s because of the `Any` type. That’s what’s surprising about the code – simply nesting a `nil` inside another optional (`.some(Optional<String>.none)`) would work as expected, printing `a equals nil`.

Comment: @zoul This is not the case, because here `a` is not `nil` in `a == nil` comparison. It's an enum value with the wrapped optional, which, in turn, is nil.

Comment: Try using `dump` just before the comparison, the outer optional was stripped by the `if let` assignment and the inner optional is `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

As the warning states:

Comparing non-optional of type Any to nil always returns false. Here the if let statement make 'a' variable a non-optional type and hence you always get false.

As for answering the original question, you have done it the right way thats how you can check for a nil value:

```
if a == nil {}
```

or like this

```
if (!a) {}
```

For more on how swift represents optional values check the answer in this question-

[Why non optional Any can hold nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644128/why-non-optional-any-can-hold-nil/34644253)

Comment: So how do we check if a is in fact nil at line 4?

Comment: sorry, i missed that. updated my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are creating another variable `a`.

But I tried your code like this and it worked:

```
let s: String? = nil
let a: Any? = s
//if let a = a {
    if a == nil {
        print("a equals nil")
    } else {
        print("a doesn't equal nil. a is \(String(describing: a))")
    }
//}
```

Comment: I am getting `a equals nil`

Comment: @JaydeepVyas :  Don't downvote immediately. At least try the code man.

Comment: you directly assign s replace with `s as Any` and it will not work

Comment: @JaydeepVyas : Dude now seriously. I am getting the output in console man.

Comment: do you know the difference between `let a: Any? = s` And `var a: Optional<Any> = .some(s as Any)`

Answer (score 0):

Nullable types present in swift as `(<YourTypy>, nil)`. For example, `String?` presents as `(String, nil)`. So, a type of `myVar: String?` can be equal `String` or `nil`.

When you use `if let a = a` structure, it moves into `true` branch only if type of `a` equals `YourType`, not `nil`. And in `true` branch you will have variable `a` with type `YourType`, not `YourType?`. So, `a` in `true` branch will never equal `nil`.

You should write notification about `nil` in `false` branch of `if let`